# Flipping all incoming/outgoing edges from a vertex in a DAG

Tags: graphs, dag

I'm working on a problem where I have a directed acyclic graph and I need to repeatedly flip all incoming (or outgoing, or both incoming and outgoing) edges from a single vertex. I think that resulting graph is still a DAG. Am I correct?

Comment: Consider the graph on the vertices $x,y,z,w$ with edges $x\to y$, $x \to z$, $y \to w$, $z \to w$. This is a DAG. If you reverse the orientation of all edges incident to $y$ then you get a directed square, which is not a DAG.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Yes, it seems you can only flip all incoming or all outgoing, not both of them at the same time

Comment: Have you tried proving that the graph remains a DAG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't hold if we flip both outgoing and incoming edges as shown by @Yuval Filmus.

Here is my try of a proof by contradiction for only flipping outgoing of incoming edges (sorry if it's too informal):

1. After flipping all incoming(outgoing) edges from vertex `v` in a DAG `G`, we get another graph that is not a DAG (it has a cycle).
2. Since we only changed the direction of the vertices incident to `v`, the only way we loose the acyclic property is if there is a new cycle going through vertex `v`.
3. Since we flipped directions of all incoming(outgoing) edges from vertex `v`, all edges incident to vertex `v` are now outgoing(incoming), so it is not possible for any cycle to go through vertex `v`, which contradicts 2.